# How to make Django Model and Views to pass JSON data to MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, django, ajax, mysql-python

I am using Quill Rich Text editor [QUILL JS Editor](https://quilljs.com/) which produces a JSON object and i want to store all the info of the editor in a MySQL data base.

[image: Console of JS]

The Code that generates this object and i am checking the data type of the data which comes out to be object type.

```
        var draft = quill.getContents();
        console.log(draft);
        console.log(typeof draft);
```

and here is another screenshot that shows how the object changes which change in the data in Editor.

[image: Console log]

I want to save this data object in the database how should i be sending this data and how will i store this in the DB?
I found that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html ,MySQL already have a JSON data type but i am not able to use this info to my advantage.

Another Link https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html

```
data = models.JSONfield(**kwargs)
```

The Model I am Using :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    postTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 30,required='true')
    subTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 50,required='false')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='userPost',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postData = models.JSONfield()
    postHeader_Image = models.FileField(upload_to= '/postHeaders/%Y/%m/')
```

UPDATE:
I was working on how to make the call to store in DB.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'some_route' %}",
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {name:$('#id_name').val()}
})
.fail(function(message) {
    alert('error');
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

I'll do this and get back to question.Please do provide any input if i can make this better or do it any other way.

Comment: Do you have a django project setup, if so what's your current view and models looking like? If not, are you asking how to get started with Django?

Comment: @schillingt Yes , i have a project setup and apps too. I also made a model but not a view. I updated Model in Question.I was look for few specific things i should take care of or use while making the views and JS code to send it to backend.